# How do you get XML comments to appear in a different project (dll)?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

```
/// <summary>
/// This method does something...
/// </summary>
public void DoSomething() 
{
    // code...
}
```

When using that method/class etc... in a different .dll the comments do not show up.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

- Make sure that your compiler is configured to emit the XML doc comments as part of the compilation job

  - The Microsoft C# compiler switch that controls this is `/doc`, and can also be configured via the `Build` property page in a project's settings
- Make sure that the XML file produced by the compiler matches the name of the DLL (i.e. `myAssembly.dll` -> `myAssembly.xml`)
- When you use the assembly in another project, make sure that the XML file is in the same directory as the DLL being referenced.

Comment: Smashing - knew it was only something simple. I'd changed my bin folder location (instead of Visual Studio's horrible default location) but not done it for the xml comments. Cheers.

Comment: I really don't understand why the people who wrote visual studio didn't set this as default.

Comment: This is working locally, the classLibProject.xml is appearing in my webapp's bin directory, and the file is getting used. however, when I deploy using Kudu's link directly to my git repo, the file is not appearing in the webapp's bin director like it does locally. what am i doing wrong?!