# intellisense not shown on public classes, but on private ones

Tags: .net, c++-cli, intellisense, .net-assembly

I am currently trying out writing my own Intellisense comments into my sources as described in
[stackoverflow 8240402](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240402/how-to-get-intellisense-for-custom-created-classes)
[stackoverflow 1632942](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632942/how-do-you-get-xml-comments-to-appear-in-a-different-project-dll)
but it's not yet working correctly. I'm using VS 2008.

I have a assembly "testAssembly" (compiled to a DLL) with `ref class class1a` and `public ref class class1b`:

```
namespace testAssembly
{
  /// <summary>
  /// Testkommentar class1a
  /// </summary>
  ref class class1a
  {
    int m_iValue;

  public:
    /// <summary>
    /// Testkommentar class1a constructor
    /// </summary>
    class1a ();
    /// Testkommentar class1a func1a
    void func1a (int i_iValue);
  };
}
```

class1b is identical.

Inside this DLL's project, it's almost working fine (although the stupid 'summary' and '/summary' are also shown in the intellisense tooltip). I do see each text except the one of `public ref class1b`.

In another project which refers the DLL's project (directly via assembly, not via file), I do see the text of (private) `ref class1a` (none of the members of course as they are private), but none of `public ref class1b`.

And when I add or remove `public`, the behaviour changes, too.

How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem:
**It's the namespace!**

After removing the namespace, all of the comments were shown.
Seems like VS2008 has problems with interpreting intellisense XML comments of different namespaces.

Can anyone confirm that?
And is there a solution for this problem?

(BTW: Which id*** downvoted my question? Is it really so useless?)

**Edit:**
It's now working correctly.
I have found the final solution: Install SP1 and a couple of hotfixes for SP1!
 - VS2008SP1DEUx1512964.iso
 - VS90SP1-KB957507-v2-DEU-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB957912-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB958017-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB960075-v2-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB963035-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB967631-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB971932-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB976656-x86.exe
 - VS90SP1-KB2498381-x86.exe
hotfix descriptions can be found on the MSDN website.