# How to use c# documentation in other projects?

Tags: c#, .net, xml-documentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get XML comments to appear in a different project (dll)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632942/how-do-you-get-xml-comments-to-appear-in-a-different-project-dll)

I have a source code of one library and every variable, method, etc. is commented there using

```
/// <summary>
/// 
/// </summary>
/// <param name="paramname"></param>
```

I've built this project and now i want to use it in another project as a dll file, but when I add reference i don't see the description of the variables, etc. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 6):

You need to turn on XML documentation in your build settings for the project. Give the XML file the same name as the assembly (so Foo.Bar.dll should come with Foo.Bar.xml). Keep the two together, and Visual Studio should pick it up automatically.