# How to include documentation in DLL to show method summary in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, dll, unity-game-engine, code-documentation

I'm working on a C# DLL plugin for Unity3D. Actually, the MonoDevelop tooltips (or Visual Studio) show only the structure of my method:

[image]

But it doesn't show my summary like this:

[image]

Even if I documented my code:

[image]

Is there a way to include my documentation in DLL?

### SOLVED WITH THIS (thanks to krillgar)

1 : Create XML documentation file on build in VisualStudio

[image]

2 : Import this XML in your Assets/Plugins folder in Unity3d

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you get XML comments to appear in a different project (dll)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632942/how-do-you-get-xml-comments-to-appear-in-a-different-project-dll)

Comment: Oh yeah, looks like a similar question.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You need to include the XML documentation file. In order to create that, you need to right-click on the Project. Under the "Build" side tab, in the "Output" section at the bottom, check the "XML documentation file" and leave the path that it creates.

When you bring your DLL over, bring that .XML file along with it, and that will put the documentation into Intellisense. <strike>I'm not sure if you'll be able to use it Unity itself, but that is how you get the summary in Visual Studio.</strike> Per probitaille's comment, you can add the XML file into the "Plugins" folder in Unity to add your comments/summaries into Unity itself.

Comment: Thanks, it work automatically if you import directly the XML documentation file in the plugins folder in Unity.

Comment: I'll add that to my answer in case your comment gets removed.